# IOS Core Data Copy (Insert) Some Objects From Entity A into Entity B

Tags: ios, core-data, insert, copy

I'm having difficulty finding the basic steps required to perform this task.

In core data, I have an EntityA, an EntityB and an EntityC.  They have some similar attributes, but not identical structure.  Following a new insert into EntityB, 
I need to fetch some objects from EntityA matching a predicate and insert them into EntityC (on the "many" side of EntityB).

What are the basic steps that need to occur?  I can create an array with a fetch but I'm unsure how to iterate through the array and match a value in A to a value in C, and insert.  I have searched the web endlessly for what would seem to me to be a common task but had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of the entities that shows the relationships and post it here?

Comment: I could but for the purposes of this discussion, relationships should not be considered and are not a concern.  In fact let's assume there are no relationships to be concerned with and I'm simply wanting to take an itemID and itemDescription from entityA and insert it into itemID and itemDescription in EntityC and there are zero relationships defined.

Comment: I've managed to do a save (insert) into EntityB, then I fetch from EntityA and insert into EntityC as desired.  Now, it appears there is a context issue as all the cascade deletes seem to be properly configured, but if I delete from EntityB, EntityC related objects in entityC should be deleted, but they are not

Comment: Your original post seemed to indicate there is a relationship between B and C.  There are 2 possible issues:  1.  How do you insert data into C.  You need to insert within the context of the an object from B not just blindingly inserting into C. 2.  Assuming that it is a one (B) to many (C), you would need to set the "Cascade" Delete Rule at the B entity.

Comment: I suspected that was the issue but I'm having difficulty wrapping my mind around dealing with multiple entities in the same context.  My old MS Access developing mindset is killing me.  I guess I need to reverse engineer the recipes app from Apple and see how they deal with these context/multiple entity issues.  Thanks